# $\arg(\frac{1-ia}{1+ia})=\arccos(\frac{1-a^2}{1+a^2})=2\arctan(a)$

Tags: complex-analysis

In the book "*Complex Analysis*" of Eberhard Freitag, an exercice ask to calculate the absolute value and an argument for $\frac{1-ia}{1+ia}$.

The answer given for the argument is $\arg(\frac{1-ia}{1+ia})=\arccos(\frac{1-a^2}{1+a^2})=2\arctan(a)$. Is anyone is able to explain to me in details why is this the case here?

Comment: Two broad hints: (1) arg(a/b) = arg(a)-arg(b) - this should follow from things you already know about arg; (2) you should be able to find the arguments of (1+ia) and (1-ia) easily with just a little bit of geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1-ia}{1+ia}$$
$$=\frac{(1-ia)^2}{1-i^2a^2}$$
$$=\frac{1-a^2-2ia}{1+a^2}$$
$$=\frac{1-a^2}{1+a^2}+i\frac{-2a}{1+a^2}$$
So we have 
$$arg\left(\frac{1-ia}{1+ia}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{2a}{1-a^2}\right)=2\arctan a = \arccos \left(\frac{1-a^2}{1+a^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a\in\mathbb{R^+}$:

$$\arg\left(\frac{1-ia}{1+ia}\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(1+ia\right)-\arg\left(1-ia\right)=$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{a}{1}\right)--\arctan\left(\frac{a}{1}\right)=$$
$$\arctan\left(a\right)+\arctan\left(a\right)=$$
$$2\arctan\left(a\right)$$